# How can I modify a user’s PATH environment variable without logging out?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

The question pretty much says it all; I have users who do not have permission to edit their own `PATH` environment variable and if they need to have it modified for some reason, they need to log out so an Admin can log in and change the `PATH` for them, before the user logs back in again. This isn't ideal. Can it be done in a better way?

Comment: Just curious - but how exactly are you preventing users from changing their own default environment?  Are you just denying them access to My Computer / Properties / Advanced / Environment Variable?  They could still modify HKCU/Environment through a variety of methods.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/189654/how-to-get-access-to-environment-variables-in-windows/189755

Comment: Group policy preferences? Just a thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always invoke a cmd shell with administrator rights (or any other runas method), and use a tool such as [SETX](http://www.ss64.com/nt/setx.html) to modify the path permanently. Existing shells and/or running programs will probably be using the old path, but any new shell/program will use the new settings.

Answer (score 28):

For accounts without admin privileges:

Open "User Accounts" and choose "Change my environment variables" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931715).

This dialog will show you your current user variables as well as the system variables. You may need to add a local PATH variable if you haven't already.

To update your Path to include the Python 3.3 directory, for instance, click New:

Variable Name: PATH
Variable Value: %PATH%;C:\Python33

This creates a local PATH by taking the current system PATH and adding to it.

Comment: I've got to think this answers, "*I have users who do not have permission to edit their own PATH*...", and does so *permanently*, better than the rest. Very nicely done. Wonder why clicking that from the My Computer is admin protected if this isn't? Just protect non-local fields the same way the UI does when accessed this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.  When my users attempt this, it prompts them for the admin password.  As I enter the admin password, it ends up opening the dialog for MY path statement.

Comment: The instructions in the linked article are tailored for Windows Vista. In Windows 10, it's easier to just open Control Panel, and go to "User Accounts" from there.

Answer (score 24):

My Computer / Properties / Advanced / Environment Variables. Changes there take effect immediately **except** for already open command prompt windows. No need to log out and back in.

**NOTE:** If you don't have access to that window, you might be able to get it by running `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` from the Run window or command-line.

Comment: regular users on my network are not able to change their own environment variables like this, unless I can open that screen with elevated privs via "run as..." or something similar, this won't work for me

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the answers above, you can also update the registry (which has the advantage of being scriptable):

The PATH variable is stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment.

To read the current path:

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH
```

To append a value c:\somedir to the path:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH /d "%PATH%;c:\somedir"
```

Note that processes read the environment when being launched, so you would have to restart the process for it to get the new path.

Update: Another way I found is to run:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Again, this applet edits the registry and has the same effect as the above.

Answer (score 5):

In a command prompt you can do:

```
set PATH=C:\somedir;%PATH%
```

but this only changes it for the command prompt (and any apps launched from the command prompt). Assuming you want this to apply to everything the user does you change the users environment variables. Right click My Computer, Properties, Advanced, Environment variables and in the "User variables for  add a variable:

```
PATH = C:\whatever
```

When the user logs in this gets added to the system wide path.

Comment: I need to change the order of entries already in the PATH, so adding removing from the User Variables doesn't work for me in this case

Comment: `setx`, as @Berzemus mentioned, can edit the system PATH variable (the `/m` switch) permanently.

Answer (score 2):

The user can set a PATH variable at a command-prompt that will override the system-wide PATH variable, even if the user doesn't have "Administrator" rights. The change will take effect for new processes the user starts from that command prompt. (The existing Explorer process, and any other processes the user is running when the change is made, will not "see" the change.)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, a user without administrator privileges can edit their own path variable by going to Settings and searching for "Edit environment variables for your account" which will pull up all of your environment variables. Then just highlighting "Path" in the top user variables box, you can click edit and set the path. Okay to save and the path should be set for any new console that's opened.